# Open file shortcut for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Mac OS X lets you navigate folders with the arrows, but I can't seem to find a way to open the highlighted file. Windows just works with Enter / Return. I can only seem to preview it with the spacebar...

I feel... stupid! :)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> (Down Arrow) work too.

See also [Enter to open a file in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/59007/enter-to-open-a-file-in-finder)

Answer (score 30):

Use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

You can also use <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to preview the file using [Quick Look](http://www.apple.com/macosx/what-is-macosx/quick-look.html).

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> is open. Pressing enter helps renaming the file.