# Remapping spacebar in Finder from windowed Quick Look to fullscreen ("slideshow")

Tags: macos, quicklook, shortcuts

In the Mac OS X Finder, Can I replace the standard option of a windowed preview (Quick Look) with a fullscreen view (Slideshow)?

Command + Option + Y = Fullscreen

Space = Windowed

Is there a way of making space perform the fullscreen mode instead?

Comment: Btw I think Opt + Space is also fullscreen.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible in Mac OS X itself, since *Space* does not actually activate a menu item, and the title of the menu item in the `File` menu changes with the name of the selected object(s).
You could learn to press `Option-Space` for fullscreen mode.

---

Alternatively, you can use hotkey/utility applications such as [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) or  [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/) for this, to intercept your key press and reroute it. The following steps are for Butler.

1. Add a *Smart Item » Keystrokes* to Butler, and move it to the *Hidden* category.
2. In the *Keys* tab, press `Cmd-Opt-Y` (which is the regular Finder key combination for fullscreen/"slideshow" Quick Look.
3. In the *Triggers* tab, press *Space* as hotkey, and confirm the dialog questioning your sanity.
4. As *Exceptions*, select *Only*, and enter "Finder" in the text box.
5. Enjoy!

A significant downside to this sledge-hammer-solution: You cannot *ever* press space in Finder to have it mean something else. Renaming folders, searching in Spotlight: *Space* is not going to work.