# right delete, home and end on iMac

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I am feeling quite uncomfortable on the iMac's small key board with the right delete, home and end buttons missing. (My maximum activity on the computer needs typing)

fn+left arrow and fn+rightarrow don't seem to do the job of home and end.

Is there a way to get some other key on the keyboard to take up these 3 functions?

Answer (score 4):

Home <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>
End <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>
Right delete <kbd>fn</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd>

Comment: I didn't understand which key you meant by the second symbol in your combination for right delete.

Comment: @Anirbit: That's the Backspace key `:)`

Answer (score 1):

`Fn-Up/Down` are `Page Up/Page Down`.

`Fn-Left/Right` and `Cmd-Up/Down` are start and end of document.

`Cmd-Left/Right` are beginning/end of line.

---

Use [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) to define a *Keystrokes* element, type e.g. `Fn+Arrow` once in the *Keys* tab, and use whatever keyboard shortcut you want to use instead *Hot Key*.

---

Use [Ukele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to define your own keyboard layout.

---

Use a full-size keyboard :-)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wonder if I am knowledgeable enough to get these softwares you recommended to run. I didn't get a full keyboard simply because it doesn't come wireless. I don't know why they couldn't make it wireless.

Comment: @Anirbit Butler is relatively easy to use. [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/181788/remapping-spacebar-in-finder-from-windowed-quick-look-to-fullscreen-slideshow/225700#225700) is a somewhat detailed description how to do this -- replace "space" with "fn/cmd-up/down/left/right".