# Move to trash by using delete instead of cmd-backspace in Finder

Tags: macos, finder

How do I remap ⌘⌫ to just `delete` in Finder in order to move items to the Trash?

<sub>And no, "that is just the way Apple works" and "This is to prevent you making mistakes" are not valid answers.</sub>

Comment: It's actually Command-Backspace. Which do you want? Delete or Backspace?

Comment: Ah, backspace it is.

Comment: +1 for the comment at the end - this site is plagued with people with such attitudes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options that both **might break Finder**.

1. You can try to adapt [this solution to map Spacebar to fullscreen Quick Look](https://superuser.com/questions/181788/remapping-spacebar-in-finder-from-windowed-quick-look-to-fullscreen-slideshow/225700#225700), but you will have the same issue: Pressing backspace anywhere (e.g. renaming a file) *will* activate the menu item.
2. You can remap the menu item [similar to what I suggest here](https://superuser.com/questions/222006/mac-osx-preview-disable-the-command-backspace-move-to-trash-keyboard-shortcut/222053#222053), entering `\U007F` as keyboard shortcut (see @Lri's answer). If the filename is part of the menu item label, this won't work. I believe menu items take precedence over text input (this could be a reason why almost no application uses "simple" shortcuts), which means you might have the same issue as with suggestion 1: breaking backspace for any alternate use.

<sup>Not on a Mac right now, so I can't test these suggestions myself. Will update the answer once I get the chance to.</sup>

Comment: Yes! Suggestion 2 works although it does break the del key when renaming files. command is: _defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add "Move to Trash" "\U007F"_