# Pressing Enter key on Mac renames the file

Tags: macos, finder

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enter to open a file in Finder](https://superuser.com/questions/59007/enter-to-open-a-file-in-finder)

Pressing Enter key on my Mac renames the file. I don't want that. I don't want to unlearn twelve years of Windows usage. I want to change the rename command to F2 and open files using Enter. Kindly help.

How can I change the key functions?

Comment: Sorry if this seems harsh but why did you get a Mac if you don't want to *unlearn 12 years of Windows*? Even if you solve this problems you will never have the same system.

Comment: Protip: When learning a new GUI environment, don't try to force it to be like some previous GUI environment you're more familiar with. Let yourself acclimate to the new system. You'll adjust to the differences very quickly, and you'll soon be able to switch back and forth with ease.

Comment: You're probably referring to the *Return* key. There's no *Enter* key on recent Macs.

Comment: @DanielBeck please don't nitpick. We all know what he is talking about.

Comment: @kino Until a few years ago, Macs came with both `Enter` and `Return` keys, e.g. [here](http://www.elektro-export.de/WebRoot/Store/Shops/es114318_Elektro-Export/4B1B/709C/5E86/BE80/599A/50ED/8961/E575/DSC_1233.JPG). `Return` is the oddly shaped one, `Enter` is directly left from the arrow keys. Today you need to press `Fn-Return` to get `Enter`. AFAIK it makes a difference in Excel on Windows as well (with numpad `Enter`).

Answer (score 3):

As a reference only: <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will open the selected item

Comment: Command + down arrow does as well.

Comment: Never heard of that one... I'll have to try it

Answer (score 2):

Remapping the <kbd>return</kbd> does not seem trivial but you get ReturnOpen (an application that maps <kbd>return</kbd> to `open`.

You could try ReturnOpen: http://www.returnopen.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/) to reconfigure keyboard/mouse/touchpad mappings to your heart's content, including remapping <kbd>return</kbd> keypresses in Finder into 
<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd>.

That said, I've gotten so used to it now that I'm looking for a way to change the behavior in windows instead. :-)